# Can't connect to localhost via browser

Tags: browser, localhost

Novice here. I can't access my localhost from any browser. I get the 'refused to connect' error from chrome and the equivalent from IE.

The other feeds on this sort of issue don't address my issue.  They describe how to access one's localhost through another application like hadoop, php, etc.  I'm just trying to access it through my browser.

Can you someone please provide a step by step, novice friendly, way to troubleshoot?

Comment: nothing listens, or your firewall blocks connections

Comment: I was able to ping fine. Will investigate firewall.

Comment: Is that a windows?

Comment: Yea, I figured it out - had to turn on some preferences in windows.

Answer (score 0):

Turn Windows features on or off >> Internet Information Services

Answer (score -1):

I've installed phptriad and got the same message. I've seen both services: mysql and Apache, but http://localost failed. Some advice said: Try "telnet localhost 80" -> result: no connection. Then I've checked all conf files and in phpgeekutil was port:1005. First I tried "telnet localhost 1005" -> no error. Heureka. Correct is "http://localhost:1005" (the port from phpgeekutil.conf).